# Vim step-by-step: How do you line up arbitrary text by arbitrary delimiter?

Tags: editor, vim

**Background:**

There are a lot of great tutorials and "tricks" pages for Vim, but one thing that is very difficult is to find *specific* instructions on how to do some arbitrary thing that one can easily do in one's own familiar text editor IDE. Therefore I am asking for step by step instructions on how you I would do something in Vim that I already know how to do in other text editors. I like Vim and the great built-in help and numerous on-line tutorials, but sometimes a human has to break down and ask another human.

**Question:**

Suppose I have the following code in my file, how can I use Vim to get from BEFORE, to AFTER?

```
  BEFORE:
  Lorem ipsum dolor |  sit amet, consectetur | adipisicing elit,
  sed do eiusmod | tempor incididunt | ut 
  labore et | dolore magna aliqua. | Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud | exercitation ullamco | laboris 
  nisi ut | aliquip ex ea commodo | consequat. Duis aute irure

  AFTER:
  Lorem ipsum dolor  |  sit amet, consectetur   |  adipisicing elit,         
  sed do eiusmod     |  tempor incididunt       |  ut                        
  labore et          |  dolore magna aliqua.    |  Ut enim ad minim veniam,  
  quis nostrud       |  exercitation ullamco    |  laboris                   
  nisi ut            |  aliquip ex ea commodo   |  consequat. Duis aute irure
```

**Notes:**

- It would be nice to do this based on any arbitrary delimiter, not just the pipe 
  character.
- If you have not found a way to do it, but you know of a plug-in, that helps, but preference goes to someone who has a working solution that they have used before

Comment: I don't have use for it, but what you're looking for is the [align.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294) plugin.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use the [Align](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294) plugin, you could simply:

1. Visually select the text with `V`
2. Type `:Align |`

Where `|` is any delimiter

OR

1. Visually select the text with `V`
2. Type `\t|`

For a preset `|` shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

It's no magic bullet, and if you're doing this a lot I hope you'll find/make a plugin, but these steps do work, don't require anything special installed, and are good to learn anyway since they generalize for a whole range of tasks.

1. `:set noet` to ensure you're not expanding tabs into spaces.
2. `:set ts=25` to set a nice large tab stop size.
3. `:%s/\w*|\w*/\t|\t/g` to add a single tab-stop around pipes instead of arbitrary spacing.
4. `:set et` to make tabs convert back into spaces when we
5. `:retab` to convert them.
6. At this point, things are nicely lined up, but there might be excessive spacing. So use visual-block mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>) to tidy stuff up.

I use combinations of things like this frequently, for a range of text manipulation tasks. Visual block mode is exceedingly useful and I haven't seen many other editors that have something comparable. See also `:help blockwise-examples`.

Answer (score 2):

Damian Conway has a series of articles about Vim at IBM Developer Works. This one:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-vim-script-2/index.html

shows how to create a function to line up assignment operators. It's in the section called *A function to help you code*. I think you could generalize it to your needs. Or use the Align plugin. I'm sometimes torn between writing my own tool, from which I can learn something, and getting somebody else's tool, which is often better than mine, and lets me get back to work more quickly.

By the way, the entire series is *excellent,* and there are more to come. The last paragraph of the last article says:

*So, in the next article in this series we’ll explore Vim’s simple plug-in architecture, which allows you to factor out parts of your .vimrc and isolate them in separate modules. We’ll look at how that plug-in system works by developing a standalone module that ameliorates some of the horrors of working with XML.*